# What happens if you play an attack card twice but the targeted enemy dies after it's played once?

Tags: slay-the-spire

Let's say I'm facing a group of two enemies. I play [Double Tap](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Double_Tap) which makes it so my next attack is played twice. I then play [Anger](https://slay-the-spire.fandom.com/wiki/Anger) which does 6 damage and target an enemy that only has 6hp. What happens when Anger gets played a second time if the enemy I was targeting dies after getting hit once? Will the second attack target a different enemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the enemy dies after the attack card gets played the first time, the card will only be played once. 1 stack of Double Tap will be used up even though the card was not played a second time.